# False or empty object if condition not working in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I'm getting false in the response from the api. If I `console.log` the result then it shows `{}`. What I want to do is, if the response is false then redirect to the homepage. But the false condition is not working. Below is my code:

```
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.token = params['Token'];
    this.common.createAPIService('api/users/recoverpassword/ValidateLink?Token=' + this.token + '', '').subscribe((result: any) => {

        console.log(result);
        if (!result || result == {} || result == false) {
            this.common.ShowNotification("Change Password", "Invalid Request", "error");
            // setTimeout(function () {
            //     window.location.href = "#";
            // }, 3000);
            console.log(12);
            this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl("/home/" + "Mumbai"));
        }
    });
});
```

I tried `!result`, `{}`, even `result == false` but it's not working. The alert in condition or `console.log` not coming. Please help.

Comment: since `console.log` shows empty `object`,you can try `Object.keys(result).length === 0`

Comment: if(Object.keys(result).length === 0) like this??

Comment: yes, you can try that

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal. Thanks brother. It worked.

Comment: Also you can do: `JSON.stringify(result) === '{}'`

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal. another issue. If response is true then also it's redirecting. In the case of true in console.log true is  getting

Comment: @SagarKodte can you share your JSON response for both the cases?

Comment: In response I only get true and false text

Comment: If I console.log result in true case It getting true in console, but in false getting empty object in console

Answer (score 0):

Use `===` instead of `==`

```
 if (!result || result === {} || result === false) {
                    this.common.ShowNotification("Change Password", "Invalid Request", "error");
                    // setTimeout(function () {
                    //     window.location.href = "#";
                    // }, 3000);
                    console.log(12);
                    this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl("/home/" + "Mumbai"));
                }
```

For more you can refer this [== vs ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you should check whether it is truthy or falsy in your condition

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy